# __set() return can't be assigned to new variable

Tags: php, oop, magic-methods

In the following code, I would like to assign "New Value" to `$o`. So my expected output for `var_dump` would be **New Value**. However, my `var_dump` is outputing  **Stackoverflow**.

I do know that PHP has multiple variable assignment, but is there a way to make it work as I expect?

EDIT: Is there a way to "bypass" the default behavior of `__set()` void return?

```
<?php

class MyTable {

    private $name;

    public function __set($p, $v) {
        # $this->{$p} = $v;

        return $this->$p();
    }

    private function name() {
        var_dump("I'm executing!");

        return "New Value!";
    }

}

    $oMyTable = new MyTable();

    $o = $oMyTable->name = 'StackOverflow';
    var_dump($o);

?>
```

You can see it live here: http://3v4l.org/b5DuF

Comment: Very, very strange way to use setter. Setter is intended to _set_ something inside object, not just return value to external scope. Why use setter then is it's just regular method?

Comment: The return of setting a variable would be the object itself, in my real code (The code on  the question is just an example).

Answer (score 0):

As the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) reads..

> The return value of __set() is ignored because of the way PHP processes the assignment operator. Similarly, __get() is never called when chaining assignments together like this:

```
$a = $obj->b = 8;
```

You might try to overwrite the `__set()` method with an experimental function [runkit_method_redefine()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-method-redefine.php) to see if that manages to substitute the `void` returned.

A way to see the result you desire returned is by calling the `__set()` method using [call_user_func()](https://www.php.net/function.call-user-func).

```
$oMyTable = new MyTable();
$o = call_user_func(array($oMyTable, '__set'), 'name', 'StackOverflow');
var_dump($o);

// string(14) "I'm executing!" string(10) "New Value!"
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in my question: `I do know that PHP has multiple variable assignment`. I'm trying another way to bypass this default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [`__set()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) magic method you'll see that it returns `void` (there is no return).

What you're seeing is the assignment of 'StackOverflow' to both variables. Possibly a combination of set and get would help you achieve this better. I'd ask a second question if you'd like to see that explained.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

> Thanks, but as I said in my question: I do know that PHP has multiple variable assignment. I'm trying another way to bypass this default behavior.

You could use a different magic method to achieve this: [__call()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call).

See if the following code makes sense:

```
<?php
class MyTable
{
    private $name;

    public function __call($name, $argument)
    {
        return $this->$name();
    }

    private function name()
    {
        var_dump('Im executing!');
        return 'New Value';
    }
}
$oMyTalbe = new MyTable();
$o = $oMyTable->name('StackOverflow');
var_dump($o);
```

I've tried to copy your style above as cloecly as possible for ease of reading.